# No number for a single li in an ol

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to not display the number for a single li in an ol. It's not an issue if it still contributes to the count of the list (I know this might seem like a strange request).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, just set the CSS [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type) property to `none` on the particular `<li>`.

```css
li.nostyle {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="nostyle">three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This hides the number, but the counting continues so that there will be a gap (1, 2, _, 4).  Is there a way to keep the counting consistent while hiding the number (1, 2, _, 3)?

Comment: The `value` attribute can be used for the LI elements, but that doesn't seem to be supported consistently. Furthermore, it doesn't seem to be accepted for EPUB2 either.

Comment: @Jens there is a way, just add value parameter <li value="3">

Answer (score 7):

This will hide your first ordered list number.

This will look strange since your hiding your first number in the ordered list. This is one possible solution through CSS

```
ol li:first-child { list-style:none }

<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: May be I should have read the question thoroughly. I thought you were referring to the first child element of an ordered list.

Answer (score 7):

*(Not the answer, but in case someone needs...)*
If you want to hide the number (bullet) of single item lists, you can use CSS3 `:only-of-type` selector.

```
li:only-of-type { list-style-type: none; }
```

This way, you won't have to assign different classes to your lists. Your lists can grow and shrink as necessary.

And this works for both ordered and unordered lists.